# Answered Questions that help Instructors

Tags: discussion, support

For those of you who are able to reply, thank you for your help. I can't vote you up on here for some reason but I appreciate you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Meta Ask Different is the place to discuss Ask Different and your question has been migrated here from the site.

Answer (score 3):

You can't comment or vote in a way that grants reputation since your account doesn't have that privilege yet.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour

Why not look over the help section and tour. Also, your votes still help the site, so be sure to vote up good posts - it doesn't give reputation directly but the system does promote posts with high anonymous positive votes when it decides how to render pages.

Welcome to the site and I hope you can find things to answer / ask and do real voting and building of knowledge for all about Apple products.